# How to install simplified Chinese IME basic input features offline on Windows 11?

Tags: windows-11, input-languages, dism, language-pack

I want to add Chinese Pinyin IME on my Windows 11 PC, which requires addition package "Basic Input" to be installed.

However my computer [cannot install optional feature, language pack, Windows Update or MS Store app due to 0x80070005 error](https://superuser.com/questions/1709662/windows-10-11-cannot-install-feature-updates-optional-features-or-store-apps-p), so I can't simply install the necessary package just in Windows Settings.

I managed to find and download an ISO file of language packs "22000.1.210604-1628.co_release_amd64fre_CLIENT_LOF_PACKAGES_OEM.iso" and extracted CAB file containing the IME input feature files (see below). But I don't know how to install it. Using LPKSetup won't work because this pack is not for display language. Any suggestions?

[image: Content of file "LanguageFeatures-Basic-zh-cn-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~.cab"]

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to install a CAB file in Windows, is to run
the Command Prompt as administrator and enter the following command:

```
dism /Online /Add-Package /PackagePath:"PATH\TO\CAB"
```

You might need to restart your computer to complete the installation.

However, it would be much preferable to fix the 0x80070005 error.
I note from your other question that even `dism` doesn't work
on your computer. So you absolutely need to fix that problem,
no other way.

Comment: The command will return 0x800f0818 error:  No providers were found that support the command(add-package).

Comment: Try in an elevated CMD to run [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html). If errors, post online for me the file `C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log` on OneDrive, Dropbox or similar. More: In *Settings > Update & Security > Troubleshoot > Additional troubleshooters*, click "Windows Update" and then "Run the troubleshooter".

Comment: Check also the SMART indicators using [Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy), as it will tell you if they are good or not. Run antivirus checks.

Comment: I have solev the problem by looping the command you provided on all "*zh-cn*.cab" files in the ISO image. It seems that there are dependencies that needed to be installed first for CAB file of IME to be installed.

Comment: Very good, and good luck in fixing the Windows Update problem.